# next.js bundle analyzer isn't creating pages to vew bundles

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm trying to reduce the bundle size of my site by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer

At the moment, when I run `npm analyze` with

```
"analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
```

It isn't outputting the html files with the visualization needed.

This is my `next.config.js`

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache')


const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
  })

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    runtimeCaching,
  },
  poweredByHeader: false,
},
withBundleAnalyzer(),

)
```

using this [nextjs-analyze-app-bundle tutorial](https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-analyze-app-bundle/).

What is going wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this has been answered [on Vercel's issues board](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19005). Copying their solution here:

> These plugins are functions that enhance the configuration object, so
> you have to wrap them instead of providing them as arguments:

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache')


const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(withPWA({
    pwa: {
        dest: 'public',
        runtimeCaching,
    },
    poweredByHeader: false,
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I was doing it like this,

```
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(
  withPWA({
    pwa: {
      dest: 'public',
      runtimeCaching,
    },
    poweredByHeader: false,
  })
)

module.exports = 
  {
    env: {
      BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    },
    future: {
      webpack5: true,
    },
    reactStrictMode: true,
  }
```

Not sure but I think you should only need to have one `module.exports` so I wrapped my other stuff inside the `withBundleAnalyzer` like this

```
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(
  withPWA({
    pwa: {
      dest: 'public',
      runtimeCaching,
    },
    poweredByHeader: false,
  }),
  {
    env: {
      BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    },
    future: {
      webpack5: true,
    },
    reactStrictMode: true,
  }
)
```